# Can SchemaCrawler transfer data to another database?

Tags: java, database, schemacrawler

If we have **oldDatabase** and **newDatabase**. In **newDatabase** table **cats** was renamed to **kittens** and was added extra table **puppies**. Would **SchemaCrawler** be able to transfer data from **oldDatabase** to **newDatabase**, recognising new table names and if there are any extra fields, just leaving them empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Please refer to the [SchemaCrawler website](http://www.SchemaCrawler.com) for a list of features.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://www.SchemaCrawler.com)